# First Occurrence of Number in Binary Search?

Tags: ruby, binary-search

I am trying to write a function, where given a sorted array, and a number, it returns the FIRST index of that number.

Is this correct? Code is in Ruby, but even if you don't know Ruby, you can pretty much understand the syntax.

```
def first(array, n)
        if(array.size == 0)
           return -1
        end

        l = 0
        u = array.size - 1

        #LOOP INVARIANT:
        # l <= startIndex <= u

        while( l != u) 
         #LOOP TERMINATES when l = u. 
         #this occurs if we reach the far right or far left without finding the #
         #or if we found the start index of the number


            m = (l+u)/2
            if(array[m] > n)
                u = m -1    # l <= startIndex <= u

            elsif(array[m] < n)
                l = m + 1   # l <= startIndex <= u

            elsif(array[m] == n)
                u = m       # l <= startIndex <= u

            end

            #LOOP always terminates because we're narrowing the range by changing l or u.
            #if there's 1 element, finding the midpoint won't narrow the range, 
            #but the while condition ends the loop anyway.
        end

        if(array[u] == n)
           return u
        else
           return -1
        end

    end
```

Comment: Could you post an example of input and output?

Comment: @HenleyChiu: you should give feedback to the people that took their time to answer and comment.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. (The elsif(array[m] == n) could be 'else' if you wanted). But.. if you are looking for correctness, why not just unit test the method will all the edge cases you can think of?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a code review, but did you know that ruby 2 introduces binary search for arrays ?

See : [Array#bsearch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch).

your problem could be solved like this:

```
myarray.each_with_index.to_a.bsearch{|(x,index)| x == n}
# => if found, returns an array containing the number and the index
```

Comment: The `Array#bsearch` reference is spot on. The problem is that, since we must index the input array, the complexity of the problem is no longer O(log n) but O(n), the same a simple `Array#index` would do (and without creating an intermediate array). I have an answer prepared with a custom `Array#bsearch`, but I am not sure there is something more elegant so I'll wait a bit...

Comment: But of course it depends on the requirements: if it's going to be 1 initialize, N searches I guess it's ok to do a O(n) pre-processing.

Comment: oh right, this did not cross my mind !

Comment: I am a bit puzzled as to why `Array#bsearch` does not return the value *and* the index. Specially in a find-minimum binary search not knowing the index is very limiting.